# Save and restart a forth 'image'

Tags: forth, gforth

I'm new to forth. I've played with gforth briefly. And I'm interesting in forth 'images'.

I have this use-case: I want to...

1. Interactively define words
2. Save the forth image
3. Quit the system
4. Restart the forth image
5. See the previously defined words

Is this possible? Could you explain how? Thank you.

(I've been playing around with `gforthmi`, `savesystem`, `gforth -i`. And I've looked at blocks and `use`. I have no real idea what I'm doing.)

Comment: This can't be an answer to the question, but I have seen the remark you made in the answers. As long as you're willing to switch to another Forth the saving facility can be much easier. I recommend my Forth (ciforth). I explained this recently in a posting in comp.lang.forth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR The workflow described in the question is not possible in Gforth out of the box.

According to the [documentation](https://gforth.org/manual/Image-Files.html), Gforth usually requires a relocatable image, but such image cannot be created in interactive session. The [word `savesystem`](https://gforth.org/manual/Non_002dRelocatable-Image-Files.html) allows to create a non-relocatable image only.

A possible approach is to log an interactive session into a file, and then use this log file to compose a conventional Forth source file that is included in the next session.

Something like:

```
tee session.log | gforth
# or
rlwrap tee session.log | gforth
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking at files as buffers. I can specify one with `use`, go to a certain `block` and even `list` a block. But I am unsure how to add a word to a buffer. Perhaps I use try another forth distribution.

Comment: Why don't to use an external editor and text files? The blocks mechanism is just a poor alternative for that.  Concerting other systems, e.g. in [SP-Forth/4](https://github.com/rufig/spf) you can [save the system](http://spf.sourceforge.net/docs/intro.en.html#save), as well as the [session log](http://spf.sourceforge.net/docs/intro.en.html#debug).